# Probability of going to the origin in a random walk

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, random-walk

Been given this as practice for my Stochastic Processes course. I'm fairly new to the concept, so I haven't been exposed to a general method. Any hints/tips for the following?

A gambler plays a (fair) game, where at each stage he has probability $\frac{1}{2}$ to
win $ \$1 $ and probability $\frac{1}{2}$ to lose $ \$1 $. If he starts with $ \$k $, what is the probability
that he will go bankrupt before $n$ games ? What is the probability that he will
eventually go bankrupt , if he plays the game indefinitely ?

Intuition tells me the last part is 1.